# Why does Vim treat \n as a valid EOL character for files in DOS format?

Tags: vim, newline, text-editor, eol

I was testing how Vim works with EOL characters.

If I create a file that looks like this:

[image]

and then load the file into Vim, explicitly stating that I want the file to be loaded in the *dos* fileformat (and not in the *unix* fileformat), the file looks like it has no errors:

[image]

How I would expect the file to be displayed:

[image]

Is there a deeper reason for this (i.e. in how Vim stores newline characters internally) or is this just a convenience mechanism in Vim, in case the person that loads the file, specifies the wrong file format? If the former, please say about the newline mechanism a little more in the context of my example.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what happens. The file format (can be `dos` or `unix`) can be detected or manually set when opening a file. If it is set to `dos`, Vim removes both `\r\n\` or `\n` from the file and replace them with its internal form of line ending (If it's `unix`, it replaces `\n` only, so `\r\n` will be left as `\r` which is displayed as `^J`).

When you write to file, Vim will replace the internal EOL with the EOL corresponding with your fileformat – CRLF for `dos`, LF for `unix`.